# Laravel ShouldUnique listener needs to pass parameter to constructor

Tags: laravel, queue

I have a listener to log customer activity and it's running in a queue. Sometimes updating the activity of a same customer overlaps and causing lock error from DB. The listener job should be defined as `ShouldUnique` to prevent this, but when I want to return the `$customer->id` in `uniqueId()` as the unique value, it's impossible to set `$customer` property value because it's not present in `__constructor()` method, and it's only available in `handle()` method. How can I achieve this?

```php
// Event
class CustomerActivity
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public $customer;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }
}


// Listener
class LogCustomerActivity implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    private int $customerId;

    public function uniqueId() {
// $this->customer is not set yet.
        return $this->customer->id;
    }


// *** This is not working! ****
    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customerId = $customer->customer_id;
    }

    public function handle(CustomerActivity $event)
    {
        $this->customer->id = $event->customer;
    }
}
```